# SOQL - how to pull list of all Asset records for an Account only if two specific Assets are present?

Tags: soql

I’ve been tasked by our sales leadership to run a report that lists all Accounts that have 2 specific Assets. Easy enough right?

However, they want to display the list of all assets under those accounts with the 2 specific assets, so I can’t just run an “Accounts with Assets” report and filter by the 2 Assets because the report would then just show the 2 Assets, not the whole list of assets for the accounts where the 2 assets were found.

Does anyone know how to pull this type of report with SOQL? I pulled an Accounts with Assets report with 0 filters to then try and accomplish this in Excel but the file is too large and Excel keeps crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar SOQL as below:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Assets) 
FROM Account 
WHERE Id IN ( SELECT AccountId FROM Asset WHERE Type__c IN ('Type A','Type B'))
```